# Regex Remove Markup Python

Tags: python, html, regex

Have a string:

```
myString = '<p>Phone Number:</p><p>706-878-8888</p>'
```

Trying to regex out all HTML tags, in this case Paragraphs.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use Regex to parse (X)HTML.  Use a parser.  BeautifulSoup comes to mind.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703017/remove-sub-string-by-using-python/8703078#8703078

Comment: I would link directly to the answer of that question @Hamish: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/147129 :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) as pointed out by a comment:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> BeautifulSoup(myString).text
u'Phone Number:706-878-8888'
```

Comment: Perfect! I kept trying attribute 'string' instead of text. Much thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
>>> re.sub('<[^>]+>', '', '<p>Phone Number:</p><p>706-878-8888</p>')
'Phone Number:706-878-8888'
```

Using `re` is a good solution if you just want to remove tags. But, if you're want to do things a little bit more complicated (involving HTML parsing) I suggest you to look into [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).