# Python: Find and remove a string starting and ending with a specific substring in python

Tags: python

I have a string and it has a number of substrings that I'd like to delete.

Each of the substrings start with `ApPle` and end with `THE BEST PIE — STRAWBERRY`.

I tried the suggestions on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32015356/find-and-remove-a-string-starting-and-ending-with-a-specific-substring-in-python), but they didn't work.

Input

> Cannoli (Italian pronunciation: [kanˈnɔːli]; Sicilian: cannula) are
>   Italian  ApPle Sep 12 THE BEST PIE —
>   STRAWBERRY pastries that
>   originated on the island of Sicily and are today a staple of Sicilian
>   cuisine[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32015356/find-and-remove-a-string-starting-and-ending-with-a-specific-substring-in-python)[2] as well as Italian-American cuisine.
>   Cannoli consist of
>   tube-shaped shells of fried pastry dough, filled with a sweet, creamy
>   filling usually ApPle Aug 4 THE BEST PIE — STRAWBERRY containing
>   ricotta. They range in size from "cannulicchi", no bigger than a
>   finger, to the fist-sized proportions typically found south of
>   Palermo, Sicily, in Piana degli Albanesi.[2]

```
import re
array = []

#open the file and delete new lines
with open('canoli.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    file = myfile.readlines()
    array = [s.rstrip('\n') for s in file]
    text = ' '.join(array)

attempt1 = re.sub(r'/ApPle+THE.BEST.PIE.-.STRAWBERRY/','',text)
attempt2 = re.sub(r'/ApPle:.*?:THE.BEST.PIE.-.STRAWBERRY/','',text)
print(attempt1)
print(attempt2)
```

Desired Output

> Cannoli (Italian pronunciation: [kanˈnɔːli]; Sicilian: cannula) are
>   Italian pastries that
>   originated on the island of Sicily and are today a staple of Sicilian
>   cuisine1[2] as well as Italian-American cuisine. Cannoli consist of
>   tube-shaped shells of fried pastry dough, filled with a sweet, creamy
>   filling usually containing
>   ricotta. They range in size from "cannulicchi", no bigger than a
>   finger, to the fist-sized proportions typically found south of
>   Palermo, Sicily, in Piana degli Albanesi.[2]

Comment: The problem is, that `.` does not math newline characters. See @Keatine's answer for a correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your regex should be: `ApPle.*?THE\sBEST\sPIE\s—\sSTRAWBERRY`

and you need to add the regex option DOTALL to handle newlines properly, try this:

```
re.sub(r'ApPle.*?THE\sBEST\sPIE\s—\sSTRAWBERRY','',text, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: How about if the phrase starts and ends with ∑. I tried `text = re.sub(r'∑.*?∑','',text)`

Comment: I did this, but it doesn't work. `text = text.replace('∑', 'DELETEDELETE')` 
`text = re.sub(r'(DELETEDELETE(.*?DELETEDELETE))','',text)`

That format works when I test it with https://www.regextester.com/94730

Comment: @Sebastian Make sure to pay attention to the flags

Comment: Not sure what flags means.

Comment: @Sebastian look at my code, then look at what you posted, mine has `flags=re.DOTALL`

Comment: Doh! I'll try, but I delete the new lines when I read-in the CSVs