# Python ObjectId from str

Tags: python

I have a str as follows:

```
str = "ObjectId('60fe547ce9d9f9fd5f03bdab')"
```

I want to convert it to `bson.objectid`. Since the `ObjectId()` function only requires the 24 digit hex string so I am achieving this with string manipulation which is definitely not the right way:

```
obj = ObjectId(str[10:34])
```

Is there a standard way or any better way to achieve this.

Edit: I receive the string data in an HTTP POST request

Comment: How did you come upon this string? Surely whatever API gave you that string has a more direct way of getting the object ID than haphazard string manipulation.

Comment: You could split the string on single quotes and take the middle part.

Comment: `str[10:-2]` is slightly less gross.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good way to achieve what you need. Sometimes the best way of doing things is the simplest. If you are worried that the number of characters in objectID changes, I would use re.sub and look for '(' and ')'
[Find and remove a string starting and ending with a specific substring in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32015356/find-and-remove-a-string-starting-and-ending-with-a-specific-substring-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Your answer seems fine. You can also use eval and exec as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python), but it has more cons than your answer.