# Remove Dates from a file name before the extension

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, list

I have some filenames in a list that have different extensions.

```
file_name_list = ['ABDCD Pattern Raw Data 1.4.2016.xlsx',
 'Jack Raw Data 1.2.2016.xlsx',
 'Farmers holdings 1.1.2016.xlsx',
 'Anne Raw Data 1.3.2016.csv',
 '120 Brewers 5-2-2018.txt']
```

I want to remove only the dates from these file names and add them to a new list. Just like this,

```
['abdcd pattern raw data.xlsx',
 'jack raw data.xlsx',
 'farmers holdings.xlsx',
 'anne raw data.csv',
 '120 brewers.txt']
```

I tired the following using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703017/remove-sub-string-by-using-python), I took the numbers off, but not how I want.

```
import re
OutputList = []
for i in file_name_list:
    lower_character = i.lower()
    OutputList.append(re.sub('[0-9.-]', '', lower_character))
```

Output,

```
['abdcd pattern raw data xlsx',
 'jack raw data xlsx',
 'farmers holdings xlsx',
 'anne raw data csv',
 ' brewers txt']
```

If you look close, it took `120` from `120 Brewers`. How can I achieve what I want? I am using `python 3`. Any suggestions would be nice.

Comment: Can we assume that the dates are all in format X.X.X or X-X-X (or any combination of dot and dashes) ?

Comment: There could be lots of corner cases ... are there any company names with numbers at the end, i.e. `brewers 120 5-2-2018.txt`? Do the dates always appear at the end, before the extension?

Comment: @Guillaume Ruchot, it is combination of both.

Comment: @user good question, yes, there can be numbers after names too. Essentially if I can find dates in `.` or `-` format just before the extension, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you also want to preserve the dates you need to use `re.split()` instead of `re.sub()` that removes the strings.

You can split based on the latest space or dot in the string as following:

```
In [59]: for x in file_name_list:
    ...:     a, date , c = re.split(r'(?=(?:(?:\.[^.]*| [^ ]*))$)', x)
    ...:     se.append(a + c)
    ...:     dates.append(date.strip())
    ...:     
    ...:     

In [60]: se
Out[60]: 
['ABDCD Pattern Raw Data.xlsx',
 'Jack Raw Data.xlsx',
 'Farmers holdings.xlsx',
 'Anne Raw Data.csv',
 '120 Brewers.txt']

In [61]: dates
Out[61]: ['1.4.2016', '1.2.2016', '1.1.2016', '1.3.2016', '5-2-2018']
```

And if you just wanna remove the dates

```
In [65]: [re.sub(r' (?:\d+[.-]){2}\d+','', x) for x in file_name_list]
Out[65]: 
['ABDCD Pattern Raw Data.xlsx',
 'Jack Raw Data.xlsx',
 'Farmers holdings.xlsx',
 'Anne Raw Data.csv',
 '120 Brewers.txt']
```

Comment: Elegant solution!

Answer (score 3):

Regex:

```
\s\d{1,2}(\.|\-)\d{1,2}\1\d{4}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DIKjxc/2)

Comment: This does now work for me for some reason, am I missing something or it is in `python 2.7`? Instead this works, `\s\d{1,2}[\.-]\d{1,2}[\.-]\d{4}`

Comment: not sure.. using the \1 was to make sure that the date separator used between month and date is used between date and year. Try changing to `\s\d{1,2}(?:\.|\-)\d{1,2}(?:\.|\-)\d{4}`

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

file_name_list = ['ABDCD Pattern Raw Data 1.4.2016.xlsx',
   'Jack Raw Data 1.2.2016.xlsx',
   'Farmers holdings 1.1.2016.xlsx',
   'Anne Raw Data 1.3.2016.csv',
   '120 Brewers 5-2-2018.txt']

for file in file_name_list:
   replaced = re.sub('\s\d{1,2}[\.-]\d{1,2}[\.-]\d{4}', '', file)
   print(replaced)
```

Output:

```
ABDCD Pattern Raw Data.xlsx
Jack Raw Data.xlsx
Farmers holdings.xlsx
Anne Raw Data.csv
120 Brewers.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The replace also took your dots, so the files no longer have an extension. I see that the dates are in multiple formats, which isn't helpful, since what you need to do is examine your data (filenames) to determine a pattern that you can use to consistently discriminate the dates and only the dates from the rest of the filename.

From what you provided, it looks like a couple of splits may be in order.  I'd split by the dot first, and then split by the space character. From the list of file name pieces, .pop the last item (the date) and .join the remainder of the list back together.  Append your extension and you'll be good.  This assumes that you have no filename dates of the format "abc xyz mm dd yyyy.ext"