# Join list element after split into str

Tags: python

Having a string like this want to remove `cksum 0x78f7` from the string or `0x78f7` this part only

I tried to split the (7 elements ) after cksum to remove `0x78f7`

```
try:
    test_str = """IP XXX cksum 0x78f7 (correct), seq XXX:XXXX,length 31"""
    sub_str = "cksum"
    sub = test_str.split(sub_str)
    print(sub[1][7:]) 
except IndexError:
    pass
```

The result

> (correct), seq XXX:XXXX,length 31

then i tried to join the two strings together

by adding

`print(sub[0].join(sub[1][7:]))` which is not working

to get this result

> IP XXX cksum (correct), seq XXX:XXXX,length 31

But the result was wrong

Comment: `sub[0] = ''.join(sub[1][7:])`. `join` is a `str` command, not a `list` one.

Comment: @MichaelGuidry that print the second element of the list without the first 7 chars without (joining the first element of the list) `(correct), seq XXX:XXXX,length 31` but i need the whole line without `cksum 0x78f7` or `0x78f7` only

Comment: So your real question is: "How do I remove specific data from a string?".  That's not this question.

Comment: i already remove but the problem with joining the string, i explained how tried to join the string after removing but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all instances of a word with your own makeshift one-liner!

```
rm = lambda s, word: ' '.join(filter(lambda _s: _s != word, s.split()))
test = 'ip xxx checksum 0x7 correct'    

>>> rm(test, 'xxx')
  'ip checksum 0x7 correct'
```

Otherwise you could use `re` module to remove all substrings as
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8703078/10277967 pointed out.

```
import re

>>> re.sub('xxx ', '', test)
  'ip checksum 0x7 correct'
```

Comment: Thanks , i need to get `IP XXX (correct), seq XXX:XXXX,length 31` or `IP XXX cksum (correct), seq XXX:XXXX,length 31`

Answer (score 0):

You can split your string into a list, and then find the index of cksum to delete the element next to it (i.e 0x78f7)

```
test_str = "IP XXX cksum 0x78f7 (correct), seq XXX:XXXX,length 31"
test_list = test_str.split()
ind = test_list.index('cksum')
test_list.pop(ind+1)
print(' '.join(test_list))
```

another option if you don't want to turn your string into a list:

```
ind = test_str.find('cksum') + len('cksum')
ind2 = test_str.find('(correct)')
print(f'{test_str[:ind]} {test_str[ind2:]}')
```